# Logic of multiplying payRate to a certain hour, and payRate*2 after

Tags: java, class, logic

Im having a hard time trying to figure out the logic of this problem. 
I am adding up the pay for an employee, and any hours they work up to 40 should be multiplied by payRate. However, any hours after the base 40 are going to be payed payRate*1.5.

This is what the question specifically says: •  Weekday hours (Mon-Fri) are paid at the pay rate. Any hours over 40 during weekdays are paid at time-and-a-half.

Here is my entire code so far, looking specifically at the getPay method at the bottom of the code:

```
public class Employee {

private double[] hours;
private String name;
private double payRate;

public Employee() {
    hours = new double[7];
}

public Employee(String name, double payRate) {
    hours = new double[7];
    this.name = name;
    this.payRate = payRate;

}

public double getHours(int i) {
    return hours[i];

}

public void setHours(int i, double num) {
    hours[i] = num;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public double getPayRate() {
    return payRate;
}

public int getNumDaysWorked() {
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < hours.length; i++) {
        if(hours[i] > 0) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

public double getTotalHours() {
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < hours.length; i++) {
        count += hours[i];
    }
    return count;
}

public double getWeekdayHours() {
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        count += hours[i];
    }
    return count;
}

public double getWeekendHours() {
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 5; i <7; i++) {
        count += hours[i];
    }
    return count;
}

public void newWeek() {
    for(int i = 0; i < hours.length; i++) {
        hours[i] = 0;
    }
    //Arrays.fill(array,0.0); ??? 
}

public double getPay() {
    double totalPay = 0.0;
    double timeHalf = (payRate * 1.5);
    double timeDouble = (payRate * 2.0);
    double bonus = 50.00;

    if(getNumDaysWorked() == 7) {
        totalPay += bonus;
    }

    if(getWeekendHours() > 0) {
        totalPay += (getWeekendHours() * timeDouble);
    }

    if(getWeekdayHours() > 40) {
        //totalPay += ()
    }

    return totalPay;
}


}
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: What I am trying to accomplish is paying a set payrate up to 40 hours in the week. Any hours after 40 will be payed a different payrate.

Comment: an example being an employee works 45 hours in the week. 40 hours will be multiplied by the payRate and added to the totalPay. Then the remaining five will be multiplied by a different payRate and then also added to the totalPay.

Comment: Think about how would would do this on pen and paper. Can you write an algebraic formula to determine pay given hours worked `h`, overtime limit `l` and overtime multiplier `m`?

Comment: Okay so I think that helped, in relation to my example above. I would do: (40*payRate) + [(45-40)*timeHalf]... timeHalf being the overtime payrate. Then that should do what I wish